# I'm being haunted by an "Authentication dialog" and need help

Tags: authentication, prompt

Like the title says I'm being haunted. No matter what I fill into the damned prompt it says the information is wrong and asks if I want to try again. It just won't stop.

Here is a picture of the satanic ritual that I must go through:
[Evil authentication thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FTrQ.png)

It is followed by this: [Dubious prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOnIj.jpg)

Now I suspect it has something to do with "Gmail feed" (seen in the 2nd picture) because I managed to raise the update timer to 90 minutes instead of 1 minute and it has helped. But I want it removed entirely. I have looked around and I've found nothing that helped me.

I should mention that I'm a monumental noob when it comes to PCs. I hope this whole deal doesn't look like I'm not serious. I'm just so annoyed by it that a lot of words just shoot out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! "Muon Package Manager" saved me. Just run Muon PM and search for "plasma-gmailfeed", right click and mark for removal. Restart and your hell is over!

I hope this can help someone else with this problem.

Thank you Muon Package Manager!